# ClusterKit for Mapbox not working correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

So I have tried implementing the ClusterKit [proj](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit) in order to have clustering of annotations/(possibly polylines)([given that Mapbox does not have that functionality](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5814)) in my app but it does not seem to work. No errors or anything it just does nothing and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

**Here is the relevant code:**

```
 viewDidLoad() {
        let algorithm = CKNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
        algorithm.cellSize = 200
        mapView1.clusterManager.algorithm = algorithm
        fetchData() //This is a call to firebase I add the annotations to an  array of them inside an annotations object. 
        setupCluster() //This gest called multiple times IDK why, not sure if its the issue but I have been unable to change this
  }
```

```
    func setupCluster() {

            mapView1.clusterManager.marginFactor = 1
            print(ObjAnnotationArray.annotations, " These are teh annotations")
            mapView1.clusterManager.annotations = ObjAnnotationArray.annotations
    }
```

These are the delagete methods whwere I added functionality as specified [in the docs](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit).

```
`    @nonobjc func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        print("Change ")
        mapView.clusterManager.updateClustersIfNeeded()
    }
```

```
`    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {

        print(annotation," ",(annotation as? CKCluster)?.count, " also: ",annotation as? CKCluster)

        if let cluster = annotation as? CKCluster, cluster.count > 1 {
            print("inside if the k=cluser functionaluty")

            let edgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 20, bottom: 44, right: 20)
            let camera = mapView.cameraThatFitsCluster(cluster, edgePadding: edgePadding)
            mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
        }
}
```

***Any help/suggestions on how to solve this?***

I have looked here at [their example](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit/blob/master/Examples/Example-swift/MapboxViewController.swift) but cant find a solution there myself.

Also, [here is the wiki](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit/wiki/Mapbox) on how to implement which I followed.

Comment: If you could supply your data points in geojson form then Mapbox does allow clustering as here: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/ Obviously the geojson is a serious limitation though and won’t work for a lot of people.

Comment: For me with a data set like snapmap I don't think it would work. That's why I have not been doing it with Mapbox's

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193233/cluster-annotation-as-ckcluster-yielding-nil-clusterkit-mapbox I don’t know what ClusterKit is but it seems kind of broken given all these questions about it.